# execve() of unistd.h, I can't make it work

Tags: linux, execve, unistd.h

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void test_sys_exec(){
    char arq[128] = "/bin/mousepad x1.txt";
    char* prms[10] = { (char*)0 };
    char* envp[10] = { (char*)0 };
    
    execve(arq, prms, envp);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    
    test_sys_exec();
    
    puts("fim");
    while(getchar() != 10);
    return 0;
}
```

Just the console window with the 'fim' message,
without appearing the mousepad window

what is wrong?

Comment: Please *read carefully* (don't guess) what the parameters of `execve` are.

Comment: When execve fails, it sets errno, so you can check to see why it failed. That may give you a hint.

Comment: Add the line `perror("execve");` right after the call to execve.

Comment: Another hint: exec functions don't return unless they encounter an error.